# Swiftui watchos navigation bar cut off

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch, watchos

I'm trying to show the entire view as the white rectangle seen in this image but no matter what I do I can't get the background behind the navigation view to change. How can I make the rectangle go behind the navigation/status bar?

[image]

```
ZStack {
  RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
}
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```